# How to transparently handle NaN values in 2D array?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, nan

I'm going to put a 2D array containing NaN values on a background image.
The background image was also loaded using Pillow.

I applied a custom color palette containing RGB values to the 2D array containing NaB values. Then, the NaN values turned black by itself. Where NaN values correspond, the background image should be visible, I want the NaN values to be transparent.

I understand that I need an alpha channel to handle it transparently in Pillow. But there is no alpha channel on the color palette I have.

Is there any way to add an alpha channel to the RGB palette I used?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the easiest way would be to convert your color palette based array to some `RGBA` image, setting the alpha channel to `0` for all `nan` values. Then, you can simply use [`Image.paste`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) to paste this image onto the background image.

I set up a small example, unknowing how exactly you store your data. So, you might need to adapt that part to your existing implementation.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Background image
bg = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
w, h = bg.size

# 2D array with values 0 - 3, and containing NaN values
a = np.random.randint(0, 4, (h, w)).astype(float)
b = (np.random.rand(h * w) < 0.90).reshape((h, w))
a[b] = np.nan

# Color palette for values 0 - 3
cp = np.array([[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [128, 128, 128]])

# Replace palette with actual RGB values, set alpha = 0 for NaN values
img = np.zeros((h, w, 4), np.uint8)
for i in np.arange(cp.shape[0]):
    img[a == i, :] = np.concatenate([cp[i, :], np.array([255])])

# Paste generated "foreground" image onto background image
img = Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8))
bg.paste(img, mask=img)
bg.save('output.png')
```

The intermediate image looks like this (four different colors set, all `nan` values were made transparent):

[image: Intermediate]

The final image (background image can be seen, where former `nan` values were located in the array):

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```